# Sum totals for columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get a sum for all columns? Say I have a table like the one below. My query gets the total costs and net return. How can I also calculate the "total" sums without writing a second query.

```
Date        rate      supplyfee     demandfee     chargedfee   othersTotalcosts  netReturn 
2010-01-10  1,339.00  2,150.00     10,000.00       120,000.00        1,085.78     1,064.22
2011-01-01  3,339.00  1,150.00     1,100.00        150,000.00        1,144.13      5.87
*Total*               3,300.00     2,100.00
```

Total costs is computed by `sum(chargedfee + others )/rate + demandfee` and net return is computed by `supplyfee - totalcosts`.

The query below computes total costs:

```
 SELECT date
        , rate
        , supply_fee
        , demand_fee
        , charged_fee
        , (charged + others/rate) + demandfee AS totalcosts
        , supplyfee-((charged + others/rate) + demandfee  AS net returns

 FROM  financies
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-10' AND '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: Tried to reformat your post, but `as net returns` and `'2010-01-10 AND' '2011-01-01'` don't look right, and you open two parenthesis while only closing one...

Comment: Redited the the post did see that one

Comment: Your formulae need clarification, they don't really make much sense verbatim

Comment: The total costs are computed by adding chargedfee with others(othersfees) then divided by the rate then adding the demandfee .the net returns are computed by subtracting supply fee from total costs hope this clarifies for the computations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to look complicated, but bear with me. It needs some clarification on what is meant by `others/rate` however the principle is sound.  If you have a primary key on financies that you can use then a more elegant (GROUP BY ... ROLLUP) solution may be viable however I've not sufficient experience with that to offer reliable advice.  Here goes how I would address the issue.

**Long-winded option**

```
(
    SELECT
        financesTallied.date,
        financesTallied.rate,
        financesTallied.supply_fee,
        financesTallied.demand_fee,
        financesTallied.charged_fee,
        financesTallied.total_costs,
        financesTallied.net_return

    FROM (

        SELECT
            financeWithNetReturn.*,
            @supplyFee := @supplyFee + financeWithNetReturn.supply_fee,
            @demandFee := @demandFee + financeWithNetReturn.demand_fee,
            @charedFee := @charedFee + financeWithNetReturn.charged_fee
        FROM 
        ( // Calculate net return based off total costs
            SELECT 
                financeData.*,
                financeData.supply_fee - financeData.total_costs AS net_return
            FROM 
            ( // Select the data
                SELECT
                    date, 
                    rate, 
                    supply_fee, 
                    demand_fee, 
                    charged_fee,
                    (supply_fee+demand_fee+charged_fee)/rate AS total_costs // need clarification on others/rate
                FROM financies
                WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-10' AND '2011-01-01'
                ORDER BY date ASC
            ) AS financeData
        ) AS financeWithNetReturn,
        (
            SELECT
                @supplyFee := 0
                @demandFee := 0
                @charedFee := 0
        ) AS variableInit
    ) AS financesTallied
) UNION (
    SELECT
        '*Total*',
        NULL,
        @supplyFee,
        @demandFee,
        @chargedFee,
        NULL,
        NULL
)
```

Working from the innermost query to the outermost.  This query selects the basic fees and calculates the total_costs for this row.  This total_costs formula will need adjustment as I'm not 100% clear on what you were looking for there.  Will refer to this as **[SQ1]**

```
            SELECT
                date, 
                rate, 
                supply_fee, 
                demand_fee, 
                charged_fee,
                (supply_fee+demand_fee+charged_fee)/rate AS total_costs // need clarification on others/rate
            FROM financies
            WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-10' AND '2011-01-01'
            ORDER BY date ASC
```

Next level up I'm just reusing the calculated total_costs column with the supply_fee column to add in a net_return column. This concludes the basic data you need per-row, will refer to this as **[SQL2]**

```
        SELECT 
            financeData.*,
            financeData.supply_fee - financeData.total_costs AS net_return
        FROM 
        ([SQ1]) AS financeData
```

At this level it's time to start tallying up the values, so need to initialise the variables required with 0 values (**[SQL3]**)

```
        SELECT
            @supplyFee := 0
            @demandFee := 0
            @charedFee := 0
```

Next level up, I'm using the calculated rows to calculate the totals (**[SQL4]**)

```
    SELECT
        financeWithNetReturn.*,
        @supplyFee := @supplyFee + financeWithNetReturn.supply_fee,
        @demandFee := @demandFee + financeWithNetReturn.demand_fee,
        @charedFee := @charedFee + financeWithNetReturn.charged_fee
    FROM 
    ([SQL2]) AS financeWithNetReturn,
    ([SQL3]) AS variableInit
```

Now finally at the top level, just need to output the desired columns without the calculated columns (**[SQL5]**)

```
SELECT
    financesTallied.date,
    financesTallied.rate,
    financesTallied.supply_fee,
    financesTallied.demand_fee,
    financesTallied.charged_fee,
    financesTallied.total_costs,
    financesTallied.net_return

FROM ([SQL4]) AS financesTallied
```

And then output it UNIONED with a totals row

```
([SQL5]) UNION (
    SELECT
        '*Total*',
        NULL,
        @supplyFee,
        @demandFee,
        @chargedFee,
        NULL,
        NULL
)
```

Comment: No problem, I quite enjoy the interesting ones.  Cleaned up my answer a bit - might be an idea to clean up these comments a bit too (will delete this one shortly)

Answer (score 0):

wrap it and add another column similar to this:

```
select date, rate, supply_fee, demand_fee, charged_fee, totalcosts, net_returns, 
 (totalcosts+net_returns+supply_fee) as grandtotal
from(
    select date, rate, supply_fee, demand_fee, charged_fee,
           (charged + others/rate) + demandfee as totalcosts,
           supplyfee-((charged + others/rate) + demandfee as net_returns
    from finances
    where date between '2010-01-10' AND '2011-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) with a `GROUP BY` clause to summurize your columns, something like:

```
select IFNULL(date, "Total") date, IFNULL(rate, "") rate, 
       supply_fee, demand_fee, charged_fee,
       (charged + others/rate) + demandfee as totalcosts,
      supplyfee-((charged + others/rate) + demandfee  as net returns
from financies
Group by date, rate WITH ROLLUP
Having date between '2010-01-10' AND '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: The query above runs successfully but zero results set is returned could the issue be with the query its self?

Comment: @smilezjim, check your data, Is there any data matching the criteria in the `Having` clasue??